# How to store .pdf files into MySQL as BLOBs using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

How to store .pdf files into MySQL as BLOBs from PHP?

Answer (score 14):

**EDITED TO ADD**: The following code is outdated and won't work in PHP 7.  See the note towards the bottom of the answer for more details.

---

Assuming a table structure of an integer ID and a blob DATA column, and assuming MySQL functions are being used to interface with the database, you could probably do something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query 'INSERT INTO table (
    data
) VALUES (
    \'' . mysql_real_escape_string (file_get_contents ('/path/to/the/file/to/store.pdf')) . '\'
);';
```

A word of warning though, storing blobs in databases is generally not considered to be the best idea as it can cause table bloat and has a number of other problems associated with it.  A better approach would be to move the file somewhere in the filesystem where it can be retrieved, and store the path to the file in the database instead of the file itself.

<del>Also, using mysql_* function calls is discouraged as those methods are effectively deprecated and aren't really built with versions of MySQL newer than 4.x in mind.  You should switch to mysqli or PDO instead.</del>

**UPDATE**: mysql_* functions are **deprecated** in PHP 5.x and are **REMOVED COMPLETELY IN PHP 7!**  You now have no choice but to switch to a more modern Database Abstraction (MySQLI, PDO).  I've decided to leave the original answer above intact for historical reasons but don't actually use it

Here's how to do it with mysqli in procedural mode:

```
$result = mysqli_query ($db, 'INSERT INTO table (
    data
) VALUES (
    \'' . mysqli_real_escape_string (file_get_contents ('/path/to/the/file/to/store.pdf'), $db) . '\'
);');
```

The ideal way of doing it is with MySQLI/PDO prepared statements.

Comment: My php code is below: $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);$esc= mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($fp));$query = "INSERT INTO table(id,data,Dealid) VALUES (49, \".$esc.\",0)";

Comment: [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) that requires a db connection for it and as the first parameter. I fell on this Q&A from someone using it as a possible duplicate. It should be updated in order to provide the proper syntax; and this for future visitors/newbies who don't know how it all works.

Comment: [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) also needs a db connection. Can you ping me once you've done that Gordon?

Comment: There should also be brackets for this `mysqli_query 'INSERT` as in `mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT... . '\');');`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Am double-checking the query, but the documentation for mysqli_real_escape_string says it doesn't need a link parameter (though if you do provide one it must be the first argument) http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @GordonM *"but the documentation for mysqli_real_escape_string says it doesn't need a link parameter"* - I think you may be talking about `mysql_real_escape_string()`. The `i` equivalent does need a connection passed for it, otherwise it will not work; last I knew.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah, you're right.  I was looking at the right documentation, but the wrong bit (the OO calling conventions, which don't need the link)

Comment: @GordonM Because the OOP method `string mysqli::` uses the mysqli construct http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, I'm aware, but it was late, I was tired and didn't notice my eyes wondering over the wrong part of the docs ;)

Comment: @GordonM Ah I see. I revisited the answer just now; I wonder why it was downvoted. I've given you a + to compensate.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I accidentally pressed the downvote button while I was viewing the total votes of the answer I was on a mobile phone, so the wrong button was pressed, been looking for this post to fix that, but I can't change that unless answer could be edit.. GordonM  Apologies, If you could just do an edit I will be able to change that

Answer (score 1):

In regards to Gordon M's answer above, the 1st and 2nd parameter in `mysqli_real_escape_string ()` call should be swapped for the newer php versions,
according to: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score -4):

```
//Pour inserer :
            $pdf = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['inputname']['tmp_name']));
            $filetype = addslashes($_FILES['inputname']['type']);//pour le test 
            $namepdf = addslashes($_FILES['inputname']['name']);            
            if (substr($filetype, 0, 11) == 'application'){
            $mysqli->query("insert into tablepdf(pdf_nom,pdf)value('$namepdf','$pdf')");
            }
//Pour afficher :
            $row = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tablepdf where id=(select max(id) from tablepdf)");
            foreach($row as $result){
                 $file=$result['pdf'];
            }
            header('Content-type: application/pdf');
            echo file_get_contents('data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode($file));
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation about your code? Please visit help center to understand how to write a good answer.

Comment: Voted to delete.  This code is a prime example of what NOT to do