# Uploading a word document, storing it on mysql and displaying it

Tags: php, html, mysql, ms-word

Hi I know php basics and that.  I've recently rediscovered it and teaching myself new techniques.  So please bear with me...

In this task, I'm to upload a MS Word document via php, store it on mysql and retrieve it when needed.

**Is this possible?**  Should a file such as a .doc be stored on the same database as first name, last name, email etc.  Or should I store it as a BLOB on a separate database for file uploads?  I'm not sure if mysql is able to read every line on a .doc file?  Thanks.  Are there any examples online for beginners like myself?
I've already done the research.  Some people say I shouldn't use mysql to store text files, other say I can.
I currently have:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<label>First Name:</label><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"/><br>
<label>Last Name:</label><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"/><br>
<label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email"/><br>
<div><label id="upload">Select file to upload:
<input type="file" id="upload" name="upload"/></label></div><br>
     <input type="submit" name=submit value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Firstly, you won't be able to upload anything; not without first including a valid enctype in the form.

Comment: You could always have a "doc_path" column and store a reference to the file in the database, rather than the doc itself.

Comment: I'd personally not store any FILES in a database, there's the FILEsystem for that. Saving a reference to the save location of the .doc in your database is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few topic to be discussed here.

**The form**

To upload the file, change the form enctype attribute.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    :
</form>
```

**Storing the file**

You could store the file in a database, or just as file in the server disk system. Whatever you choose, it is not necessary to split the file into its lines. Store the file as a single unit.

[Read this entry which discusses the topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959043/how-to-insert-a-file-in-mysql-database)

It should suffice to say here that your database field should be an appropriate type and size to hold the file.

Personally, I am a fan on storing the file on disk, and the file name on the database.

**File upload handling**

You can save the file somwehere on disk. This is not the best way to do it, but the simplest to demostrate. There are enough example on SO, for example [How to upload & Save Files with Desired name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509333/how-to-upload-save-files-with-desired-name)

```
 $info = pathinfo($_FILES['upload']['name']);
 $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
 $newname = "newname.".$ext; 

 $target = 'mydocs/'.$newname;
 move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target);
```

**Downloading the file**
To have the file displayed and download, merely print the contents out to the browser.

```
ob_start();
 // do things. See below
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
ob_flush();
```

This will display the file and probably confuse the browser. To tell the browser to handle the file as a Word document, you must send the appropriate headers to the browser before sending the file.

```
    ob_start();
    if(isset($_REQUEST['dlink']))
    {
        $file = $_REQUEST['dlink'];
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
         exit;
    }
ob_flush();
```