# PHP move existing files on the server to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a huge number of files existing on some server and I want to move them all to mysql instead.
What is the best way to do that in terms of performance as I mentioned the number of files is pretty big . And if there is any 3rd party script existing to do that.

Comment: what do u mean by move them to mysql ? is it saving the entire data in each file to mysql tables??

Comment: `files` to database ?? !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert a file in MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959043/how-to-insert-a-file-in-mysql-database)

Comment: i think he means data files.  i believe he wants a solution to moving data stored in files to database.

Comment: @UmairKhan How can you assume the OP wants to store the *data* stored in the file in MySQL? AFAIK, he wants to store the *file* itself.

Comment: I said I think , so further clarification from the OP is required. You have right to disagree :)

Comment: I have files I want to read those files and store them as blob. I know that's a bad practice because I already storing them to HDD and only store a link to that file. But my customer want them to be move to a database.

Answer (score -2):

You should NEVER store your files in MySQL. Keep your files in a folder, and put the paths to the files in your database.

The reason why you shouldn't do it, is because the filesystem itself are optimized for one thing.. Storing files, you'll have way more performance storing the files on disk compared to a database. Sure a database usually have a lot of data in memory, since MySQL tries to put everything in memory if it can.

But the filesystem does the same. Frequently accessed files will end up in memory to save IO on the disk itself, you can read more about this with file system cache and virtfs.

Comment: I am doing that but the customer insists to store files in database