# ASP.NET Core EF - Getting an error when uploading a file

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am developing a system using ASP.NET Core, EF Core and my database are MySQL and I am using MySQL Connector.NET as the adapter.

I have a place in my system where the user can choose a file and upload. My question is, when I try to upload a file which is more than 1000 KB, I am getting the following error:

> An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

The database field for this file is of a `LONGBLOB` type and the type of the modal is `byte[]`. The error is thrown right inside the `dbcontext.SaveChanges()` method which is why it is hard to debug and identify the reason.

I will post the full stack trace below:

```
   at MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.SocketByteHandler.WriteBytesAsync(ArraySegment`1 data, IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Protocol\Serialization\SocketByteHandler.cs:line 90
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySqlConnector.Utilities.ValueTaskExtensions.<ContinueWith>d__0`2.MoveNext() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Utilities\ValueTaskExtensions.cs:line 8
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.TryAsyncContinuation(Task`1 task) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 1225
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySqlConnector.Core.TextCommandExecutor.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\TextCommandExecutor.cs:line 36
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.<ExecuteNonQueryAsync>d__60.MoveNext() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlCommand.cs:line 261
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlCommand.cs:line 62
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlTransaction.cs:line 81
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTransaction.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Zoneberry.Repository.ZONContext.SaveChanges() in path\ZONContext.cs:line 157
   at path.Commit() in project\UnitOfWork.cs:line 419
   at project.Controller.UploadFileFor(List`1 files, Int32 leadId, Int32 totalCount) in project\Controllers\LeadController.cs:line 220
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
```

The system works fine when I upload files which are smaller than 1MB.

Comment: It's not a great idea to store large files in SQL for a variety of reasons, see for example https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17314/what-is-bigger-than-a-longblob, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959043/how-to-insert-a-file-in-mysql-database/5959059.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have a limit in a `MySql` side. Try to execute this command on `MySql` server:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

If the result is near `1 million` bytes, then you need to increase that value (e.g almost 2 MB) by running the following command:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=2000000;
```

But this setting will be reset after server reboot.
To change the setting permanently you need to change it in `my.ini` or `~/.my.cnf` under `[mysqld]` section:

```
max_allowed_packet=2M
```