# How to store a .docx file into MySQL - and open it?

Tags: mysql, blob

**MySQL**

```
CREATE TABLE document_control (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
person VARCHAR(40),
dateSent TIMESTAMP,
fileAttachment MEDIUMBLOB
);
```

**MySQL Insert record query**

```
INSERT INTO DOCUMENT_CONTROL (fileattachment) values (load_file('C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\test.docx'));
```

**Retrieving record**

If I run this query here: `SELECT * FROM document_control` - Everything is null - even after the insert query above.

**Question**

Why is the values `null`? and also.. how can I properly store a `.docx` file into MySQL and open the file?

Comment: why didn't you go with, store file on server location and save path in MySQL and retrieve file from location when you need it?

Comment: Anyone can access the server - and delete it by accident

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a file in MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959043/how-to-insert-a-file-in-mysql-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into [SQL blob data type](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/sql/sqlserver/export-documents-saved-as-blob-binary-from-sql-server/)

You could also read the file as bytes, convert it into a string or base64 encoding or something, and then save that as string in database.

You could also choose to save the file-reference (file path of file) to refer to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer  -the link seems useful - will update you If I have accomplished anything