# Store multimedia fileuploads through a webapp

Tags: database, web-applications, file-upload, filesystems, store

I'm developing a webapp based on Spring with Hibernate and I want to use a MySQL database to store multimedia files through a fileupload mechanism. I don't know what is the best way to do it, I mean, Can I store files into the database directly? or do I have to keep a reference in the database and store the files in the filesystem?

I'm thinking in the second approach but I don't know how to desing the model for the database. I have a user profile, and ever user can store differents files like photos, music or videos. Then I'm thinking in an entity User related to an entity MultimediaAlbum with an N to N relationship. That mean I have 3 tables (User, MultimediaAlbum, and a relationship table).

Futhermore, I want to make accesible these multimedia files through web services, so I need a link for these files. And finally, I don't know where to store these files in the filesystem.

Thank you very much for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post for storing files as blobs in MySQL: [How to store .pdf files into MySQL as BLOBs using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813913/how-to-store-pdf-files-into-mysql-as-blob-from-php)

Personally I prefer to store files uploaded in a database. I've only done it a few times, but some quick reasons why:

1. Easier to avoid orphaned files. If someone deletes a file, you only delete it from the database. You don't have to search the file system and delete it there as well.
2. If you don't do security right and people upload scripts/programs, it should be safer to have them in a database instead of on the file system of the server. (Although I'm sure creative people can still do damage with a file in the database.)