# how to save file in mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have database:

```
id_meas int(255)     (id)
NK      int(255) NULL    
K       int(255) NULL    
Sp      int(255) NULL    
data    blob     NULL
```

How should I write a file in row data and the others lanes?

```
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    $data = getPosts();
    $insert_Query = "INSERT INTO `measurement`(`id_meas`, `NK`, `K`, `Sp`, `data`) VALUES ('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]', '$data[4]')";
    try{
        $insert_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $insert_Query);

        if($insert_Result)
        {
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
            {
                echo 'Data Inserted';
            }else{
                echo 'Data Not Inserted';
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Error Insert '.$ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: i think storing file in database is not god practice

Comment: i need write csv file without Mysql workbench

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How about this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813913/how-to-store-pdf-files-into-mysql-as-blobs-using-php