# Storing and retrieving PDF File in Mysql Database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

How can i store and retrieve a PDF file into a Mysql database? Havent found any thing reasonable on here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store .pdf files into MySQL as BLOBs using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813913/how-to-store-pdf-files-into-mysql-as-blobs-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$value = file_get_contents('yourpdf.pdf')
```

Then record $value in your database.

Comment: then how about displaying it? and Do i get to save it as BLOB?

Comment: U can't save file directly to database, u can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php this to move it and then this to open it http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php . In database u need to save path to this file.

Comment: i have used move_uploaded_file to move to a folder i call resume. When you say save path to file, you you mean the tmp?

Comment: $temp = $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"];
$name = $_FILES["avatar"]["name"]; 
$size = $_FILES["avatar"]["size"];

move_uploaded_file($temp, __SITE_PATH . "/pictures/" . $name);

$path = URL . '/pictures/' . $name;

This is basic example. U need to save in DB $path

Comment: i managed to use ma calculations and indeed i was able to catch what you meant. did this <?php

$resume_dir = '\resume/';
$cv_path = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. $resume_dir . $resume;

?> and it saved to a location, then i used $row['cv_path'] to hyperlink it and then it was able to view. Thanks again.